# How would you implement session-based auth with SvelteKit and an external REST API

Tags: authentication, svelte, sveltekit

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to use SvelteKit to implement session-based auth with an external REST API.

I'm able to successfully make `POST` requests to an external login API from a `+page.svelte` page when the user submits a login form. The external API successfully validates the credentials and sends back a `sessionid` cookie, which I presume needs to be sent back to the server in the HTTP request header on every subsequent external API call that requires authentication.

However, I don't know how to access this `sessionid` cookie and send it as an HTTP request header on all subsequent `fetch` requests to authenticated endpoints (not SvelteKit endpoints, external API endpoints). Part of my confusion here is how much of the auth I should be handling in `+page.ts` load functions vs. `+page.server.ts` load functions (for pages that require authentication), since you can [only access cookies](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#cookies-and-headers) in `*.server.*` files.

For example, the docs say that `fetch` [on the server can make credentialed requests](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#making-fetch-requests). Does that mean that every credentialed request (i.e. with the sessionid) must be done in a `*.server.*` file? That doesn't seem right--you wouldn't be able to make arbitrary credentialed `fetch` requests from the client ever then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem: the server was returning a `sessionid` cookie on a client-side `fetch` call to login, but that cookie was not being set by the browser on subsequent requests. That's because that original `fetch` call to login did not have `{ credentials: 'include' }`. I incorrectly assumed that you only needed that on subsequent calls where you wanted the cookies sent, but it turns out you also need it on the first call that gets the cookie response from the server.

Managing user state on the client is pretty straightforward after that: just keep a `user` object in a SvelteKit store and check if it exists. If it does, assume you're logged in. If you ever get a subsequent `401` from the server, assume that your session was invalidated and unset that `user` from the store.